# Accessing an Audio File From a Different Folder

Tags: html, cloud9

I am doing a project for my computer science class in which I am adding audio into my website. I am doing this in cloud 9. And I have a folder of different songs on a different folder. I need to be able to access the song from the higher folder. People have been saying to use this code:

```
    <source src="../folder/filename.mp3" type=mpeg">
```

But the code was given to me fro images, I have not been able to do it with a song. When I use this code I get the normal looking play button on my website, but it is grayed out. I have been able to get it to work, but only if I take the song out of the folder and put it at the same level as the file. I have also tested different audio files to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute site URI routing whereby your sound file address starts with a `/` and so indicates the path from the root of the URL.

For instance:
Your current output file is, say, `www.site.com/output/file.html`, and you want to load a sound from, say, `www.site.com/sounds/laugh.mp3` then you simply use the `/sounds/laugh.mp3` part of the address as your reference. Becauseit starts with a `/` this indicates it's an absolute site URL and indicates the root HTML directory, rather than a page specific url.

```
 <source src="/sounds/filename.mp3" type=mpeg">
```

If you used a *relative* path such as `../sounds/filename.mp3` this would break if you used it in the base folder (`www.site.com/index.html`) or in a deeper directory tree such as `www.site.com/sounds/silly/horses.html`. But the absolute path would always work (as long as the destinaton file exists and is accessible).

---

Tip: Make sure you've also uploaded your sound file!

Comment: Sorry 'bout that hit enter by accident. My file directory is, The folder project, from inside is the folder music in as well as the file Music.html(my website). I tried your code like this  <source src="/Music/Concerto.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> (sorry I don't know how to make it show up like code). I still get the blank

Comment: your link is case sensitive, and so it would be `www.site.com/Music/Concerto.mp3` ? (code view in comments is using backticks (next to number 1 on keyboard, usually)). Does that link exist?